# Ping6 routing between interfaces failing

Tags: networking

Spent the last two weeks googling every IPv6 gateway and routing example and none seem quite like this. I have three machines setup in the following configuration:

Machine A has IP of 2001:cdda:2011::1 on dev eth0.

Machine B has IP of 2001:cdda:2011::2 on dev eth0, 
2001:cdda:2012::2 on dev eth1, and has all forwarding configured to 1.

Machine C has IP of 2001:cdda:2012::3 on dev eth1.

Ping6 from Machine A to Machine B, IP 2001:cdda:2011::2 works.

Ping6 from Machine B to Machine C, IP 2001:cdda:2012::3 works.

Ping6 from Machine C to Machine A, IP 2001:cdda:2011::1 fails. If I manually configure the route on Machine A telling it how to get to Machine C it works, but I am attempting to setup a mobile network where the route from A to C and vice versa is not static therefore I cannot preconfigure this route.

Essentially I am restricted from using pre-defined routes or default routes, as the hop from A to B may not be there at all times. (There will always be a router on device ETH0 with access to Machine C via ETH1, it just won't always be Machine B). Does anybody have insight on how to do this?

Respectfully, Riley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using static IPv6 addresses, you also need to set up IPv6 static routes. You can't get around that. You can run a routing protocol, but that would be overkill in this situation.

You instead want to use router-assigned addresses, namely SLAAC, so that the default route will be provided with the address.

Maybe start here to understand the basics: https://community.infoblox.com/t5/IPv6-CoE-Blog/SLAAC-to-Basics-Part-1-of-2/ba-p/11356

And then set up Machine B as a router, since that is what it is. http://www.tomicki.net/ipv6.router.php

Comment: Thank you sir!! After carefully following your links and using RADVD on Machine B, it is working. The addresses on Machines A and C are receiving their addresses and default routes automatically from Machine B. Ping6 from end to end is successful.

Comment: Great to hear! Please upvote my answer so it can help others.

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't have enough standing to have upvote rights yet. Thanks again!